# How do I show first Grid row first when application load

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

It appears that my Grid layout is set for the the second row is displaying first.

When the application loads Grid.Row="2" which is the middle part of the page show first.
I have to scroll down to see the carousel witch Grid.Row="1"
I am trying to figure out the carousel the at the top then the video the the Change program last.

Here is my xaml code.

```
 <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="Center">
 <Grid x:Name="page" Padding="0,0"> 
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <RowDefinition Height="600" /> 
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0"> 
 <CarouselView x:Name="carousel" Scrolled="Handle_Scrolled" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"> 
<CarouselView.Behaviors> 
<behaviors:FrontBannerViewParallaxBehavior ParallaxOffset="100"/> 
</CarouselView.Behaviors>
<CarouselView.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate> <Grid Padding="18,24,18,64"> <custom:PancakeView 
CornerRadius="24" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"> <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill"     
HorizontalOptions="Fill"> <custom:PancakeView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" 
CornerRadius="10" BackgroundGradientStartColor="{Binding StartColor}"       
BackgroundGradientEndColor="{Binding EndColor}"> <Grid> <StackLayout> <StackLayout 
Orientation="Horizontal"> <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="{StaticResource 
font_extrabold}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="#60229a" VerticalOptions="End" 
 Margin="14,0,0,0" FontSize="36" FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" /> </StackLayout> 
<Label FontFamily="{StaticResource font_regular}" Text="{Binding Details}" TextColor="#60229a" 
Margin="14,8,24,24" FontSize="22" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" /> </StackLayout> </Grid> 
 </custom:PancakeView> </StackLayout> </custom:PancakeView> <Image Source="{Binding ImageSrc}" 
  WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
  Margin="0,0,15,0" /> </Grid> </DataTemplate> </CarouselView.ItemTemplate> 
 </CarouselView> 
 </StackLayout>
 <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">`
       `<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Listen to Apostle Johnson's" FontFamily="{StaticResource 
font_extrabold}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="#FFFFFF" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="14,0,0,0" FontSize="36" FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource font_regular}"  Text="Detox Transformation." TextColor="#FFFFFF" Margin="14,8,24,24" FontSize="22" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource font_regular}" Text="Apostle Johnson gives a 
riveting short bio of his testimony of traveling a road of living a life of descriptive chaos.  Hey just click on the video and hear it from him." TextColor="#FFFFFF" Margin="14,8,24,24" FontSize="22" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ovideo:VideoPlayer x:Name="vmo" Source="http://iowegodministry.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/y2mate.com-FROM-GANGSTA-TO-GOD_JeR29HVa7HE_360p.mp4" WidthRequest="250" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout> 
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Chance Program" FontFamily="{StaticResource font_extrabold}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="#FFFFFF" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="14,0,0,0" FontSize="36" FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Label FontFamily="{StaticResource font_regular}"  Text="The mission of C.H.A.N.C.E. is to help people succeed in the workforce by providing training and mentorship.  One of the goals is to help those who've been in the prison system become successful members of society after they get out.  The program will provide clas`enter code here`ses on a variety of spiritual-based educational curriculum, teach job interview skills, and help with strengthening family relationships and bonds." TextColor="#FFFFFF" Margin="14,8,24,24" FontSize="22" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
        <Button BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" 
                FontFamily="{StaticResource font_bold}" 
                Padding="20,0" CornerRadius="20" 
                TextColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" 
                FontSize="12" BorderColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" 
                BorderWidth="2" HeightRequest="40" 
                Text="Read More About the Program" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
                />
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
  

   
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

From shared **Xaml** code , used `ScrollView` as RootLayout . ScrollView has a [ScrollToAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scroll-programmatically) method to scroll to one position into View . You can have a try with this to scroll to your wanted position when application loads.

A position within a `ScrollView` can be scrolled to with the `ScrollToAsync` method that accepts double `x` and `y` arguments.

Given a vertical `ScrollView` object named **scrollView**, the following example shows how to scroll to `150` device-independent units from the top of the `ScrollView`:

```
await scrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, 150, true);
```